# how to build keter bundle for yesod web app that is one package of many in a stack build

Tags: haskell, yesod, haskell-stack, keter

I have a project that contains several packages that are specified in one stack.yaml file. One of these packages is the yesod application. It depends on the other packages. `stack build` handles dependencies nicely, but how do I build the keter bundle for the web app?

When I do `stack exec -- yesod keter` from inside the app package, it does happily re-compile all of the other packages (starts by unregistering all, then configure, build, copy/register). That takes much too long.

In the top level directory, I don't see how to `yesod keter` so I can only create the keter bundle manually (by calling `tar cvfz ...`)

This does not feel right because I have to provide redundant information (e.g., location of the executable needs to be listed in `keter.yml`, and is also needed as argument for `tar`), and I need to manually copy files (`app/{config,static}/*`)